# How do I send to the action parameter value from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, bootstrap-4

```
         <form class="form-horizontal"
              action="{{ path('category_view', {'program': 'category' }) }}"
              data-ajax-method="get"
              {#onclick="return makeModal(this);"#}>
                        <label for="category" class="col-sm-1 control-label">
                            Category
                        </label>
            <select id="ddlFruits" class="form-control">
                <option value="all">All</option>
                <option value="stress">Stress</option>
                <option value="media">Media</option>
                <option value="mulidrive">Multidrive</option>
                <option value="security">Security</option>
            </select>
         </form>
```

How do I pass selected value from dropdown to `program`?

Answer (score 0):

use .val() to get your value, so would be $('#ddlFruits').val() ;.